# Why do ELL posts need to be edited before reversing a downvote to an upvote?

Tags: support, editing, votes

I mistakenly downvoted a question and would like to change it to upvote. However, the ELL system requires the edit first before changing. Why and for what purpose? Anytime I try to change from downvote to upvote, a message appears "You last voted this question **** minutes ago. Your vote is locked unlesss this question is edited". Is this function necessary?

Comment: I have often wondered the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie Interestingly? This function makes users with their rep under 2000 unable to reverse and IMO this function gives this community no good benefit.

Comment: One can see why they allow you to change after an edit, but not why it's so crucial to lock them.  Or, indeed, what the point is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not something we can reconsider as English Language Learners; it's a network-wide feature known as [vote lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80763/295232). That answer on Meta Stack Exchange provides some rationale behind this decision:

> This helps to prevent irregularities in voting. If I could go back and take away every up vote I ever made, more than a few people would see a 1k + drop in reputation. If you thought the post was good, or not good for the duration of the grace period, the system assumes you knew what you were doing when voting either way.
>
> ...
>
> This is in order to help curb the [tactical down-vote problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046/295232).